# Enabling both http and https in apache 2 with defaults redirection to https while enabling http

Tags: apache-2.2, http, https

I want to configure my apache2 server as www.example.com site can be view as http and also https.
Another thing i need that if i type one **"example.com"** it will go for **https**://www.example.com
and if i type "http://www.example.com" it will go only **http**, emphasis on **"http"**.
I mean to say, if i put only domain name it will go **"https"** protocol and if i by force write http with domain name, it will go for **"http"** protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force HTTPS as the preferred protocol, this is coded into the browser. If a user configures his browser to prefer HTTPS (for example using a plugin like HTTPS Everywhere) it will do that, otherwise it will default to HTTP.

What you can do is implement [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) with your HTTP requests.

You just have to add its header to your responses:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

The next time the browser visits this site (in the given time frame) it will prefer HTTPS and skip the HTTP request. But this will not work for first time visits to your site, only for subsequent visits.

Comment: if i use URL redirection code in apache2 config file it will auto forward 80 request to 443 port. But need to enable both port open as described earlier in the post that:
if i put only domain name it will go "https" protocol (if i use url redirection in config file) and if i by force write http with domain name, it will go for "http" protocol.

Comment: What you want is not possible to configure on a server. This can only be configured on the client. My suggestion is the closest solution I can think of for your situation.

Comment: can you please tell me how this be done in client side? 
If any browser configuration issue?
I need this because we implemented SSL cert in client webserver.